# Pass a custom arg to an npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a `preinstall` script that runs on a global install that does some fanciness before the full install takes place. I need that script to be able to read some sort of custom option the user passes from the NPM install such as:

```
npm install my-app -g --unicorns
```

It doesn't really matter how I pass it, it's literally a boolean value that I need. It's just one extra detail I need to pass into the app.

Is there any way to do this?